# SharePoint Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I would like to know about SharePoint 2016 upgrade to 2019 on-premise.

Does SharePoint support in-place upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In-place upgrade is not supported. Review the documentation [Upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-to-sharepoint-server-2019) for information on how to perform a 2016 to 2019 upgrade using the database attach method.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do the in place upgrade.only supported way is database upgrade or using 3rd party tools.

You can review this article "**[Overview of the upgrade process to SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/overview-of-the-upgrade-process-2019)**" for more information